# How to make Apache Zeppelin notebook run faster on the first job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

[image: zeppelin notebook snapshot]

As you can refer to the snapshot, when the fist time you run the Apache Zeppelin notebook, it takes a long time to complete the job (approx. more than 1 min).

Is there any way to optimize to reduce the running time ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I found that in two cases you can make it faster , in spark version < 1.6 and have full resource in cluster.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer :**

You can't make the first job faster.

**Longer answer :**

Job processing isn't slow but initializing a `SparkSession` or `SparkContext` on the other is.

What Zeppelin does is initiating a Spark session on the first job you call. Simple example :

[image]

It took a minute as well to do a simple value assignation.

So there is nothing actually you can do about it to make it faster unless `spark` itself become faster to start.

Answer (score 0):

zeppelin is asking for the resource it was required to interpret your command.
In case yarn-client mode, it also needs to wait until yarn accept your application..
So, It is more than 1min for your first notebook..